# Запрет передвижения ползунка слайдера jquery ui

Tags: jquery, slider, ui

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли как то запретить движение ползунка в слайдере выше определённого значения? http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: А теперь по русски и четко сформулируй вопрос!
Что куда почему и как.

Comment: Например есть слайдер с одним ползунком с диапазоном от 0 до 10.Как сделать так что бы при одном условии я мог его двигать только например до 9ти,при другом условии например до 5ти и тд. Т.е. при первом случаи нужно запретить перемещение на 10ку а при втором сделать перемещение только до 5ки и что бы выше 5ки он не мог двигаться.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({ 
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    range: true,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.value > 8) {
            return false;
        }
    }       
});
```